# Packing functions meant for resolve into a reusable module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'm refactoring my Angular app according to [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) (well, mostly) and am in the process of making my app more modular. I've ran into a problem with route resolves. Up until this point I used a global app variable to hold my Angular app. My services also looked like this:

```
"use strict";
var usersService = app.service("usersService", ["$http", function ($http) {
    var userService = {};
    var endpoint = ClientSettings.authServiceUrl + "users";

    var get = function () {
        return $http.get(endpoint);
    };

    var getUser = function (id) {
        return $http.get(endpoint + "/" + id);
    };

    userService.get = get;
    userService.getUser = getUser;

    return userService;
}]);

usersService.loadUser = ["usersService", "authService", function(usersService, authService) {
    return usersService
        .getUser(authService.authentication.id)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
}];
```

Now when I try to refactor this, I get:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("App.Auth")
        .service("usersService", usersService);

        usersService.$inject = ["$http"];

    function usersService($http) {
        var endpoint = ClientSettings.authServiceUrl + "users";

        var service = {
            get: get,
            getUser: getUser
        };
        return service;     

        var get = function () {
            return $http.get(endpoint);
        };

        var getUser = function (id) {
            return $http.get(endpoint + "/" + id);
        };
    }
})();
```

But I hit a problem with `usersService.loadUser`. This is a function meant to be used only for resolves like so:

```
.state("profile", {
    url : "/profile",
    controller : "profileController",
    templateUrl : "profile.html",
    resolve : {
        user : usersService.loadUser
    }
})
```

`UsersService` is a part of an `Auth` module, but routes are configured in the module where the app resides.

I want this module to provide a set of functions that are meant to be used for resolves. My goal is to minimize code duplication and this would certainly do a lot for that.

## SOLUTION

This is based on the [answer by estus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585374/packing-functions-meant-for-resolve-into-a-reusable-module/32585993#32585993) below (it's the accepted one).

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("App.Auth")
        .provider("usersService", usersServiceProvider);

    function usersServiceProvider() {
        usersService.$inject = ["$http"];
        loadUser.$inject = ["usersService", "authService"];

        var provider = {
            $get: usersService,
            loadUser: loadUser
        }
        return provider;

        function usersService($http) {
            var endpoint = ClientSettings.authServiceUrl + "users";

            var service = {
                get: get,
                getUser: getUser
            };
            return service;

            var get = function () {
                return $http.get(endpoint);
            };

            var getUser = function (id) {
                return $http.get(endpoint + "/" + id);
            };
        }

        function loadUser(usersService, authService) {
            return usersService
                .getUser(authService.authentication.id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    }
})();
```

> NOTE: If you're using `ngAnnotate`, you will have to manually specify `/*@ngInject*/` for injectable functions (`loadUser` in this case) as it doesn't seem to recognize it. At least at the time of writing this.

You then inject the `provider` into the `config` function and have access your `resolve`-ready functions like so:

```
.state("profile", {
    url : "/profile",
    controller : "profileController",
    templateUrl : "profile.html",
    resolve : {
        user : usersServiceProvider.loadUser
    }
})
```

This works because, while `service`s aren't available at the time of `config`, they're available when `resolve`s are being resolved.

There's also no need to have the `resolve`-ready functions in the `usersServiceProvider` as long as it's a `provider`. That's because it's the only type of injectable type of providers available at `config` phase. I do it like this, because it allows me to keep related functionality in the same place.

Comment: Not clear what the specific problem is. Also  (non-related) ... using `$q` to resolve `$http` requests is an anti pattern according to same style guide. `$http` already returns promise

Comment: The problem is in the last paragraph - I'm looking for a way to package a set of functions like ```loadUser``` in a module, that can then be used by an app that has that module as a dependacy, for resolving routes. As for using ```$q``` to resolve ```$http```, can you point me to the section of the section of the guide? This is a simple example, where, it could easily be replaced, but in some cases I have to do manipulation of data or need just a part of the data API returned for the resolution. Also the ```usersService.getUser``` can be used elsewhere.

Comment: to only return part of data in request , chain `then` callbacks rather than using `success` which is being deprecated per `$http` docs

Comment: Haven't realized that ```success``` and ```error``` are getting deprecated. Thanks. I've edited the question with your suggestion. Is that better?

Comment: close...there is no `deferred.reject()`, second argument of `then` is the reject callback itself

Comment: Missed that one. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding resolver methods in a single service is bad for practical reasons. States are defined in `config`, where you don't have `usersService` injected, that's `resolve` that does service injection. So the above code will be workable with this

```
resolve : {
    user : function (usersService, $injector) {
        return $injector(usersService.loadUser);
    }
}
```

Looks like the refactoring goes the wrong way.

However, this can be avoided by making `usersService` a `provider` service, so `usersServiceProvider` can be injected into `config`, and `usersServiceProvider.loadUser` can be used as a resolver.

> My goal is to minimize code duplication and this would certainly do a
>   lot for that.

Minimize it by doing the common job in `usersService` and keeping resolvers in separate services. There's no benefit (more like the opposite of it) in packing `loadUser` into `usersService`.

Comment: Thanks! This works really nicely, even though it took me a bit to get my mind around what you said. I've added a _solution_ section to my answer to show how I ended up implementing it. Now each ```service``` can have a functions that can be used in the ```resolve``` phase. This lets me keep related functionality close.

Comment: Usually provider methods are used to help the service to set up (as $routeProvider and $stateProvider do, for ex.). But I see no real harm in using them as a namespace like you did.